# How to set the maximum laptop brightness after startup on my ASUS laptop?

Tags: linux-mint, display, laptop, brightness

How to set the maximum laptop brightness after startup on my ASUS laptop?

When I power on my laptop, it only has about 30% display brightness set.

Naturally, I want to set the maximum laptop screen brightness after startup on my Asus N750JV.

I am running Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon.

I presume there will have to be some startup script written in order to achieve that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My own solution, that worked for me:

Go to a directory, where this information is stored

```
cd /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/
```

Find out the maximum brightness of your display:

```
cat max_brightness
```

In the following step, use `echo` *your-maximum-brightness*, mine is 5273:

Write a script e.g. named `set-max-brightness.sh` with the following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 5273 >/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
```

Let's say we now have this file stored as:

```
/home/user/set-max-brightness.sh
```

Now, we assign it to root by running:

```
sudo chown root:root /home/user/set-max-brightness.sh
```

Then, we make it executable and limit user rights with:

```
sudo chmod 744 /home/user/set-max-brightness.sh
```

Finally, we make the script run at every boot using CRON:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

This will bring up `root`'s CRON edit, just add this at the bottom of the file:

```
@reboot /home/user/set-max-brightness.sh
```